# Please provide credentials error pushing to Azure DevOps

Tags: powershell, nuget, visual-studio-2019, nuget-package

I am getting the error

> "Please provide credentials for: https://jbright.pkgs.visualstudio.com/Project/_packaging/Project_Feed/nuget/v3/index.json"

from Visual Studio 2019 Community Powershell when I run the command:

```
nuget push -Source https://jbright.pkgs.visualstudio.com/Project/_packaging/Project_Feed/nuget/v3/index.json -ApiKey az C:\Users\Jens\source\repos\Project\Packed\Project.Core.0.4.0.7.nupkg
```

I've tried what I've been able to find online to fix this including:

- Deleting all credentials in Windows Credential Manager
- Removing and re-adding this package source in Visual Studio Package
  Manager settings

I have a nuget.config file in the project directory that contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <clear />
    <add key="Core_Feed" value="https://jbright.pkgs.visualstudio.com/Project/_packaging/Project_Feed/nuget/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>

<!--

nuget push -Source https://jbright.pkgs.visualstudio.com/Project/_packaging/Project_Feed/nuget/v3/index.json -ApiKey az C:\Users\Jens\source\repos\Project\Packed\Project.Core.0.4.0.7.nupkg  

-->
```

I keep the powershell command syntax in the file so I don't forget it, but as you can see it is commented out. The thing is, this works fine on my laptop with the same files.

When I delete the credentials in credential manager and then pull packages from this Azure DevOps feed, I get the packages and see the new credentials added to Windows. But even so, I cannot pucs a package to the feed without getting the "Please provide credentials' error.

Any idea how to fix this?
thanks,
Jens

Comment: What nuget.exe version did you use? Please try to use the latest nuget.exe cli from [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-exe-cli-reference) to push your nuget. Besides, check your nuget.config file and add the `packageSourceCredentials` node under nuget.config like [this link's info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file#packagesourcecredentials).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I delete the credentials in credential manager and then pull
>   packages from this Azure DevOps feed, I get the packages and see the
>   new credentials added to Windows. But even so, I cannot pucs a package
>   to the feed without getting the "Please provide credentials' error.

**First**, please try to use the newest version of nuget.exe cli from [this link](https://www.nuget.org/downloads) and then config the `nuget.exe cli` path from the local agent into System Environment variable **PATH**.

**Second**, you should add `packageSourceCredentials` for your private nuget package source in `Nuget.config` file:

```
<packageSourceCredentials>
    <Core_Feed>
        <add key="Username" value="xxx" />
        <add key="Password" value="xxx" />
       xxx
    </Core_Feed>

</packageSourceCredentials>
```

More info you can refer to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file#packagesourcecredentials).

**Then**, test whether you can push your nuget packages.

Comment: This is funny. I was struggling on this and after your answer found out that my nuget version is old :D